# sending email with excel attachment using C# Console app

Tags: c#, console

`I am trying to sending email through C# console app. In this I want to attach excel file. That file will not be save any where directly send as attachment with email. Here i have also retrive data through datatable using store procdure.
Note: here i have to use also App.config
please help me with some code.

here i have tried some code in program.cs

```
 using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office;

using ClosedXML.Excel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
//using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace EmailConfiguration
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            //EmailNotification en = new EmailNotification();
            EmailNotification.SendMail("minaxi.singh@ajsas.com", "Send a Mail", "Sending email demo");
            Console.WriteLine("Mail Sent ");
        }
        //created one static class
        public static class EmailNotification
        {
            //added four datatype
           const string SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
            const int SmtpPort = 587;
            const string FromAddress = "nqtest@nsa.com";
            const string Password = "Neoqt@2022";

 

            //createing send mail method
            public static void SendMail(string toAddress, string Subject, string body)
            {
                var client = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer, SmtpPort)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromAddress, Password),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.To.Add("minaxi.singh@neant.com");





                //send mail to multiple person
                foreach (var item in toAddress.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    message.To.Add(item);
                }
                message.From = new MailAddress(FromAddress);
                message.Body = body;
                message.Subject = Subject;
               // DataTable dt = GetUserData();
                GetUserData();

                ExportToExcel(dt, "E:\\Minaxi");


                // Attachment attachment = new Attachment("GetExcelFile.c", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                //message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                //GetExcelFiles _getExcelFiles = new GetExcelFiles();
                // var str =  

                try
                {
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            public static DataSet GetUserData()
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iMixClaimConnection"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_pg_AttachmentForMailing", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        ds = new DataSet();

                        da.Fill(ds);
                        // dt = ds.Tables[0];
                     

                       


                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ds.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                return ds;
            }
 public  void ExportToExcel()
                {
                DataSet ds = GetUserData();
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
                    wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                    wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                   HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserReport.xlsx");

                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. SO is no code delivering service. You need to put some effort into this. Please read [ask] and try to improve your question.

Comment: @burnsi please check it i have edit my code .